# files not being uploaded in multiple viewin sharepoint 2010

Tags: file-upload

I am able to use the multiple upload view in sharepoint 2010 but the files are not uploaded, so the process goes but the files never show in the location, how can I fix this issue? thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Does the single upload work? I suspect some scripting issue. Before clicking upload, press F12 to open your IE Debugger. Click on the Script tab and click Start Debugging. Upload the files and check if you get a script error. Also, use ULSVIEWER to check the Sharepoint logs for an exception.

Comment: Sounds like they might be uploaded but not checked in. They would only be visible to the uploader (not even admins unless using the 'Manage files which have no checked in version' link from library settings)